# Angular Material button with icon and text render the wrong way around

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this very simple Angular Material Button:

```
  <button mat-button>
    Testing
    <mat-icon>expand_more</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

but the text and icon render the opposite way around

[image]

I've added no styling so what is causing this?

This is the rendered HTML;

```
<button _ngcontent-rod-c335="" mat-button="" class="mdc-button mat-mdc-button mat-unthemed mat-mdc-button-base">
  <span class="mat-mdc-button-persistent-ripple mdc-button__ripple"></span>
  <mat-icon _ngcontent-rod-c335="" role="img" class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-ligature-font mat-icon-no-color" aria-hidden="true" data-mat-icon-type="font">expand_more</mat-icon>
  <span class="mdc-button__label"> Testing </span>
  <span class="mat-mdc-focus-indicator"></span>
  <span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-mdc-button-ripple" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></span>
  <span class="mat-mdc-button-touch-target"></span>
</button>
```

I'm using Angular v15

Answer (score 6):

If You want to position your icon to the end of the button use `iconPositionEnd` directive on `mat-icon`. I found this solution in Migration to MDC-based Components guide on Angular Material documentation: https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#button

Answer (score 1):

That indeed looks not alright. In the meantime, my solution would be to create a reusable `button` component defining if you want an icon to the left or right of the text. Of course you could add all the necessary configurations later on:

**button HTML**

```html
<button 
  color="primary"
  [class.reverse]="reverse" 
  mat-raised-button>HELLO
  <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
</button>
```

**button component**

```
@Component({...})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() reverse = false;
}
```

**button styles (.scss)**

```css
.reverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;

  mat-icon {
    padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

`reverse` with `false` => `<app-button></app-button>`

[image]

`reverse` with `true` => `<app-button [reverse]="true"></app-button>`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [buttons guidelines of Material](https://m3.material.io/components/buttons/guidelines#89ba49e3-31b5-47ae-9665-3e7f33452d0f), placing the icon to the right of a label is only allowed for right-to-left languages. That's the rule followed by the Angular Material development team that you shoul not modify if you want to follow the Material rules.

If you try to use the [Angular Material Menu component](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview) (I think it would be the right component for your use case) it will render in the same way:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu <mat-icon>expand_more</mat-icon></button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

[image]